# Phison 2309 susceptible to Bad USB?

Tags: badusb

I've got two Kingston DataTraveler 100 G3s, each with 32GB capacity. I checked their controllers and both have the Phison 2309 controllers in them. I've tried Googling around to check if the PS2309 controllers are also susceptible to the Bad USB attack, but this wasn't clear for me.

On brandonlw's Psychson GitHub repo for the attack I found a presumably incomplete [list](https://github.com/brandonlw/Psychson/wiki/Known-Supported-Devices) of susceptible controller chips to the Bad USB attack. However the description of this list is a bit confusing to me, could someone tell me from their experiences if the PS2309 controllers still are susceptible to this?

Below is a report of my run with Flash Drive Information Extractor, I'm using version 9.2.0.627:

```
Controller: Phison PS2309
Possible Memory Chip(s): Not available
Flash ID: 2CA40832 A1
Chip F/W: 08.03.5D
Firmware Date: 2018-05-04
ID_BLK Ver.: 1.4.36.0
MP Ver.: MPALL v5.35.36
VID: 0951
PID: 1666
Manufactere: Kingston
Product: DataTraveler 3.0
Query Vendor ID: Kingston
Query Product ID: DataTraveler 3.0
Query Product Revision PMAP
Physical Disk Capacity: 31029460992 Bytes
Windows Disk Capacity: 0 Bytes
Internal Tags: 2Q6P-SX5K
USB Version: 3.10
Declared Power: 504mA
ContaMeas ID: 93C2-07-00
```